# How to create single PDF document with both portrait and landscape page using iTextSharp

Tags: itext

I have been able to create portrait pages, and landscape pages in separate documents, but now require to do this in one document.  I am using ITextSharp library and the document.setpagesize seems to apply to all pages.  Is this correct?

I was using PDFLib and changing page orientation was not a problem in that library.

Any suggestions?
Paul.

Answer (score 5):

It should only apply to pages rendered after that call.

```
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.WHAT_EVER);
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter( doc, outputStream );
doc.open();
// so long as you set the page size before add()ing anything, it should ignore the
// page sized used in the constructor.
doc.setPageSize(PageSize.LETTER); // 8.5" x 11"
// actually, I think you need to call newPage or actually add enough stuff to start a new page
// for setPageSize to take effect.  setPageSize by itself won't do the trick.
doc.add(stuffToFillALetterPageButNotStartANewOne); 

doc.setPageSize(new Rectangle(792f, 612f)); // 11" x 8.5"
doc.add(moreStuffToFillALandscapePageThusStartingANewPage);
doc.close();
```

The resulting PDF should have two pages.  The will be 8.5x11, the other 11x8.5.  Note that iText[sharp] won't generate rotated pages (8.5"x11" @ 90 degrees (or 270... *shudder*)).  It's... sharper than that.

Dealing with rotated pages is Not Fun.  At least I've never run into one that was 8.5x11 at 180 rotation in my TOO_MANY_YEARS of experience with PDF.  I'd just have to fly into a murderous rage at that point.  Or maybe I should generate some PDFs that way just to see who I could catch with their pants down.

[insert fiendish cackle here]

Comment: Yes, setting new page size will affect only after doc.NewPage.